# Can I assign Objects operators? "e.g. +, -"

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

So I have a simple **Javascript** Object:

```
function Vector(x, y){
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;

     this.magnitude = function(){};
     this.add = function(vector){};
     this.minus = function(vector){};
     this.normalise = function(){};
     this.dot = function(vector){}  

     //...
}
```

---

I would like to perform the following operations:

```
var a = new Vector(1,1);
var b = new Vector(10,5);
var c = a + b
a += c;
// ... and so on
```

I know that it's possible to implement **operators** for Objects in other languages, would be great if I could do it in Javascript

---

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: The term you're looking for is "overload".

Comment: i would suggest you make  Vector return some value before you can do that operation... and remove 'new', so it's like var a = Vector(1,1);

Comment: thanks Reigel! Would you be able to show me an example of what you mean please? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in JavaScript.

You can specify what happens to your object in numerical contexts:

```
Vector.prototype.valueOf = function() { return 123; };

(new Vector(1,1)) + 1; // 124
```

... but I don't think this is what you're after.

How about offering a `plus` method? -

```
Vector.prototype.plus = function(v) {
    return /* New vector, adding this + v */;
};

var a = new Vector(1,1);
var b = new Vector(10,5);
var c = a.plus(b);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I already have the plus method, but I really hate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, ECMAScript/Javascript doesn't support operator overloading. It was proposed for ECMAScript 4 but the proposal wasn't accepted. You can still define a method which does the same thing as `+`, though -- just call `.add()` instead.